# Trying to create a random baord layout for pre-school puzzle app

Tags: java

I'm making a app that has 4 puzzle pieces , that consist of one of the alphabet letters.  The top of the screen will have 4 alphabet letters in black put in random locations.  The child will drag the color letters (on the bottom) on top of the corsponding black letter.

Right now the black letters will some times overlap, or be very close to each other.  I was trying to figure out a way to make random setups where the black letters are evenly disrupted over the board area.  Is there a edy way to do this? (ie determine x, y locations with a given width and h for each piece)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this in two steps:

1) Find a enclosing circle radius for the letters

2) Use a random generator which generates points with a minimum distance. Basically drop points which are to close and generate a new one.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the board this may lead to slow generation or even infinite looping if not correctly controlled.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out how to detect when this happens, and move one of the offending letters when it does.